# Como alterar o proprietário da conta para o Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: visual-studio-online

Iniciei um projeto no Visual Studio Team services com uma conta associada ao meu e-mail pessoal, agora quero alterar o e-mail proprietário desta conta para e-mail do meu cliente, o que faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acesse seu projeto

> https://*{suaconta}*.visualstudio.com/_projects

- clique no ícone da engrenagem
- vá em Settings
- clique em Change (Current owner)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]